# How to execute a command if a checkbox in tkinter changes its state

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Im currently coding a math training program, and now added a `settings` page. I tried to make  an entry require that the checkbox above it is checked, but i failed. I tried many times and different things and it did not work. The checkbutton is `_w2.death_mode` and the stuff it was suppossed to trigger were the entry `falsche_ants_benötigt` und the label `label_falsche_ants`.

here is the code responsible for this misery:

deathmode button:

```
w2.death_mode.place(relx=0.444, rely=0.156, relheight=0.065,relwidth=0.378)
        _w2.death_mode.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(anchor='w')
        _w2.death_mode.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(compound='left')
        _w2.death_mode.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(foreground="#000000")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        _w2.death_mode.configure(justify='left')
        _w2.death_mode.configure(text='''Death Mode''')
        _w2.death_mode.bind('<Activate>', lambda e: death_mode(e))
```

deathmode function:

```
def death_mode(*args):

    deathallowed = _w2.death_mode.instate(['selected'])
    
    if deathallowed is True:

        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.delete(0, END)
    if deathallowed is False:

        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

Entry and Label:

```
_w2.label_falsche_ants = tk.Label(_w2.Frame2)
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.place(relx=0.444, rely=0.234, height=21, width=155)
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(anchor='w')
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(compound='left')
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(foreground="#000000")
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(text='''Tödliche Antwortenzahl''')
        _w2.label_falsche_ants.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt = tk.Entry(_w2.Frame2)
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.place(relx=0.735, rely=0.234, height=20, relwidth=0.161)
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(background="white")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(foreground="#000000")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(insertbackground="black")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(selectbackground="blue")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(selectforeground="white")
        _w2.falsche_ants_benötigt.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

The way its suppossed to work, is that you can only enter a number of false responses after checking the death mode box.
But it does **not** work :(

Comment: sadly it does not :(
i tried whats shown in there but its something completely different

Comment: Are you aware that the checkbutton has a `command` attribute?